# Accessing a global variable from within an object method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

I've got a fairly simple JavaScript object with some object methods, and I'm trying to access/modify information in an array (stored in a global variable) from inside one of these methods. Here's my code:

```
var list= [];
function person(firstname, age){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.age = age;

this.addPerson = function (){
list.push({firstname, age });
}

this.addPerson();

this.changeName = function (name, newname) {
    var i = 0
    for (i; i < list.length; i++);{
        if (list[i].firstname === name){
            list[i].firstname = newname;
        }
       }
    }
 }

var person = new Bunny('Jim', 20);
var person = new Bunny('Sally',40);
person.changeName('Jim', 'John');
```

When a new person is created, they are automatically added to my list. When I call changeName, I want to input the name I want to change and the new name that it should be. However, I'm getting the error message "Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined," which makes me think that changeName can't access my list.

Comment: What is the point of function `addPerson`? Why don't you `push` person directly within the constructor?

Comment: I wrote addPerson, because I wanted to push the person to the list as soon as I created a new one. I couldn't get it to work without calling addPerson(); within the constructor....I'm sure there's a better way to do this. What would you do?

Comment: Just see my answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **2** different problems,

1. The problem is with the usage of `;` after the for loop's parenthesis. That actually causes the loop body to run once with the last incremented value of your for loop.

   ```
   for (i; i < list.length; i++);{ 
   //---------------------------^   Remove it
   ```

   That is why you are getting *cannot read property of undefined* error

   ```
   for(var i=0;i<list.length; i++); //this will run repeatedly as per for loop semantics

   { }  //and this body will be executed only once with the final updated value of i
   ```
2. You are wrongly initiating the object by using `Bunny`. That should
   be `person` in our case.

   ```
   var person1 = new person('Sally',40);
   person1.changeName('Jim', 'John');
   ```

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry I got confused. Found the real reason and updated it.

Comment: Ah! That worked! Also, "Bunny" was a stupid artifact left over from something else...should have caught that...facepalm. Thank you!!

Comment: @Lisa Glad to help! :) Try to press the tick mark present inside this answer, if you think that this answer has helped you solving your issue. And this is not a compulsion.

Answer (score 1):

Besides some syntax errors, your code is still poorly designed. Here is a better one.

```
function People(){
    this.list = [];
}
People.prototype.add = function(person){
    this.list.push(person);
};
People.prototype.changeName = function(name,newName){
    for(var i=0;i<this.list.length;i++){
        var person = this.list[i];
        if(person.firstname === name){
            person.firstname = newName;
        }
    }
};
function Person(firstname,age){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.age = age;
}

//Usage
var jim = new Person('Jim', 20);
var sally = new Person('Sally',40);

var people = new People();
people.add(jim);
people.add(sally);
people.changeName('Jim', 'John');
```

Comment: Ah, this is really helpful. I've been struggling a little bit with prototypes. So People.prototype.add/People.prototype.changeName just defines the "add" and "changeName" methods for person and makes those built-in methods for a person object? Hope that was clear...I'm still a little new to this.

Comment: @Lisa No, it doesn't work that way. These 2 methods won't be assigned to  each person. I put `add` and `changeName` in class `People` simply because it makes more sense.

Comment: OK, thanks-- but then you'd still have to call add separately, instead of automatically adding a newly created Person to list, which is what I wanted to do originally. I guess this is just better form, though?

Comment: @Lisa You can call `people.add(this)` within the `Person` constructor. I don't recommend it, simply because it's less readable and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var list = [];

var Bunny = function (firstname, age){
    //this.firstname = firstname;
    //this.age = age;

this.addPerson = function (){
list.push({'firstname':firstname,'age': age });
}

this.addPerson();

this.changeName = function (name, newname) {
    var i = 0


    for (i; i < list.length; i++){

        if (list[i].firstname === name){
            list[i].firstname = newname;
        }
       }
    }
 }

var person = new Bunny('Jim', 20);
var person = new Bunny('Sally',40);
person.changeName('Jim', 'John');
console.log(list[0]);
```

you had ';' in for loop, this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @rajaprabhu's comments:

You have a constructor method, person(). You should rename this to Person(), to conform to common coding standards for a constructor method.

You are creating 2 instances of a Person (incorrectly in your code using Bunny) Within the context of a "Person" object you have access to its own scope, meaning you can change its own properties directly. Where you are looping through the list array in the changeName method, you are reaching outside of the object's scope. Replace the loop with the following 1 line of code:

```
this.firstName = newName;
```

Also, you're not pushing either person into your list array. Instead of

```
var person = new Bunny('Jim', 20);
```

Do this:

```
list.push(new Person('Jim', 20);
```

This will add a new Person object to the list array.

Full edit:

```
var list = [];

function Person(firstname, age) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.age = age;

  this.addPerson = function() {
    list.push({
      firstname,
      age
    });
  }

  this.addPerson();

  this.changeName = function(name, newname) {
    var i = 0
    if (this.name == newname) {
        this.name = newName;
    }
  }
}

// add the Person objects directly to the list array
list.push(new Person('Jim', 20));
list.push(new Person('Sally', 40));

// now you can select an object in the list to change its name
list[1].changeName('Jim', 'John');
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful!